# Cocoon fields are not affected by JS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cocoon-gem

I'm using cocoon to create quotes for my users. A `Quote` has_many `Expense Categories`, and each `Expense Category` has many `Expenses`

I added some JS, so that everytime my user changes the value of an expense, it updates the total price in another input, but this doesn't work with the newly created inputs.

I made sure they all had the same classes (.expense .price-input)
I tried with this little piece of code:

```
  $('.expense .price-input').keyup(function () {
    alert('OK');
  });
```

When I type something in the existing inputs, OK is displayed. When I  create an expense, typing something in the newly created input won't trigger it. Is there something to initialize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Events are bound to the fields during the initial page loading, which means dynamically added fields won't be bound.

You can however add such an event binding to a parent that exists when the page is loaded, such as document, and pass the selector as an argument to the function.

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.expense .price-input', function(){
  alert('OK');
});
```

Comment: YAY ! Thanks a lot !